# Patching StockForecasted Javascript Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, patch, stock, odoo-16

Could someone help me how to patch StockForecasted in Odoo16?

```
class StockForecasted extends Component{
    async _getReportValues(){
        ​   ​this.resModel = this.context.active_model || (this.context.params && this.context.params.active_model);
    ​   ​....
    ​}
}
```

I tried this below code but did not work

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import { patch } from '@web/core/utils/patch';
import { StockForecasted } from "@stock/stock_forecasted/stock_forecasted";
console.log(StockForecasted)
patch(StockForecasted.prototype, 'test_my_stock.StockForecasted', {
    async _getReportValues(){
        console.log('_getReportValuesInherit')
        this.resModel = this.context.active_model || (this.context.params && this.context.params.active_model);
        if (!this.resModel) {
            if (this.props.action.res_model) {
                const actionModel = await this.orm.read('ir.model', [Number(this.props.action.res_model)], ['model']);
                if (actionModel.length && actionModel[0].model) {
                    this.resModel = actionModel[0].model
                }
            } else if (this.props.action._originalAction) {
                const originalContextAction = JSON.parse(this.props.action._originalAction).context;
                if (originalContextAction) {
                    this.resModel = originalContextAction.active_model
                }
            }
        }
```

Browser showed 'undefined'. I think this is because this class is not 'export'. But I cannot export this class. This is Odoo code base.

Comment: Could you provide some browser full logs with `debug=assets` enabled in the url? where are you seeing the undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Odoo failed to import it from `stock/stock_forecasted/stock_forecasted`
You should see the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: StockForecasted is undefined
```

If you check the `stock/static/src/stock_forecasted/stock_forecasted.js` file, you will see that they added the `StockForecasted` component to `actions` registry as [replenish_report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/stock/static/src/stock_forecasted/stock_forecasted.js#L130C35-L130C51)

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { patch } from '@web/core/utils/patch';
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import "@stock/stock_forecasted/stock_forecasted";
const actionRegistry = registry.category("actions");

const StockForecasted = actionRegistry.get('replenish_report');

patch(StockForecasted.prototype, 'test_my_stock.StockForecasted', {
    async _getReportValues(){
        console.log('_getReportValuesInherit')
        await this._super(...arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, brilliant. I have a question regarding 'import "@stock/stock_forecasted/stock_forecasted";'. Without this line, it doesn't work. I thought the moment Odoo load this file, its already add the 'replenish_report' into registry.

Comment: The line is used to make sure the replenish report is already imported, you can check this [issue](https://github.com/odoo/owl/issues/1070)